# Join two tables, matching a column with multiple values

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to get a product matching some custom parameters.
So I have to three tables - products, parameters and parametersitems.

Products table:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  `Title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Content` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Price` float(10,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Parameter table:

```
CREATE TABLE `parameters` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Label` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Parameter items table:

```
CREATE TABLE `parametersitems` (
  `ProductID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ParameterID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ProductID`,`ParameterID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

So my question is how can I get only the products matching all the parameters.

The only way I could think of is joining the parameteritems table couple of times.
For example, here is a query to get the products matching two parameters:

```
SELECT 
    products.*
FROM 
    products 

INNER JOIN 
    parametersitems AS paritems1
    ON  
        paritems1.ItemID = products.ID 
        AND paritems1.ParameterID = 7

INNER JOIN 
    parametersitems AS paritems2
    ON  
        paritems2.ItemID = products.ID 
        AND paritems2.ParameterID = 11
```

My only concern is that the SELECT query will get slower and slower if there more parameters selected. 
So is there a better way to handle this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select p.*
from products p
inner join (
    select ItemID
    from parametersitems 
    where ParameterID in (7, 11)
    group by ItemID
    having count(distinct ParameterID) = 2
) pm on p.ID = pm.ItemID
```

Comment: After a little bit of testing, I can say that this method is the fastest one. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Adjust the value tested in the HAVING clause to match the number of values listed in the IN clause.

```
SELECT p.*
    FROM products p
    WHERE p.ID IN (SELECT pi.ItemID
                       FROM parameteritems pi
                       WHERE pi.ItemID = p.ID
                           AND pi.ParameterID IN (7,11)
                       GROUP BY pi.ItemID
                       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pi.ParameterID) = 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works just fine, but it's slower then using the INNER JOIN method that I mentioned above. For some reason, when I explain the query, it doesn't use the PRIMARY INDEX (products.ID). I even tried to force it, but I still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  p.ID, p.Title, p.Content, p.Price
FROM 
  products AS p
INNER JOIN 
  parametersitems AS pi ON pi.ProductID = p.ID
GROUP BY
  p.ID, p.Title, p.Content, p.Price
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pi.ParameterID) = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM parameters);
```

This will always get you products matching every parameter no matter how many parameters you add. (This could become bogus if you delete a parameter without deleting the corresponding rows in paramatersitems. This is what constraints are for.)